# Docker resolver connect failed: dial udp connect network is unreachable

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

**How can I investigate the root cause of a network is unreachable in Docker?** I'm using Docker in swarm mode with docker-compose. My logs look like this they are full with this.

```
Jun 05 12:23:22 myServer dockerd[6151]: time="2019-06-05T12:23:22.996311465+02:00" level=warning msg="[resolver] connect failed: dial udp 10.58.194.11:53: connect: network is unreachable"
Jun 05 12:23:22 myServer dockerd[6151]: time="2019-06-05T12:23:22.996246500+02:00" level=warning msg="[resolver] connect failed: dial udp 10.58.194.16:53: connect: network is unreachable"
Jun 05 12:23:22 myServer dockerd[6151]: time="2019-06-05T12:23:22.996342243+02:00" level=warning msg="[resolver] connect failed: dial udp 10.58.194.11:53: connect: network is unreachable"
```

- RedHat 7.5 Linux server
- Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44
- docker-compose version 1.19.0, build 9e633ef
- docker-compose.yml version: version: "3.4"

Docker info:

```
Containers: 121
 Running: 115
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 752
Server Version: 18.02.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: v7bi5f4cnbzmq4hrnbw6xlev8
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 5wpoqhzk0vphn1grirb7y34jk
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.49.0.242
 Manager Addresses:
  10.49.0.242:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55
runc version: 9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 47GiB
Name: myServer
ID: V5I2:SAMK:WAEE:TLGM:ZA7M:5C4D:A2DK:TQVA:462K:DA7M:RTAT:QDSF
Docker Root Dir: /net/volume/fs0/dckrdata
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: http://localhost:3128
HTTPS Proxy: http://localhost:3128
No Proxy: .myApp.com,localhost,127.0.0.1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 docker.myApp.com
 registry:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Did you define custom DNS servers?

Comment: How can I figure this out?